# Python OOP - Class relationships

Tags: python, oop

Assuming I have a system of three Classes.
The `GameClass` creates instances of both other classes upon initialization.

```
class FieldClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        return
    def AnswerAQuestion( self ):    
        return 42

class PlayerClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        return
    def DoMagicHere( self ):
        # Access "AnswerAQuestion" located in the "FieldClass" instance in "GameClass"
        pass

class GameClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.Field = FieldClass()
        self.Player = PlayerClass()
```

What would be the best way of accessing `AnswerAQuestion()` located in `FieldClass` from within the instance of `PlayerClass`?

- Do I have to pass a reference to the `FieldClass` instance to `PlayerClass`?
- Is there another, better way of solving this? Doing the above would make me have to include an additional variable in `PlayerClass` to hold the `FieldClass` instance.
- Is there a completely different way of managing class relationships in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection): instantiate a `GameClass` with the required `FieldClass` and `PlayerClass` in the constructor call etc.  (i.e. instead of creating the dependent objects from within `GameClass` as you are doing at the moment).

```
class GameClass:
    def __init__( self, fc, pc ):
        self.Field = fc
        self.Player = pc

class PlayerClass:
    def __init__( self, fc ):
        self.fc = fc

    def DoMagicHere( self ):
        # use self.fc
        pass

fc=FieldClass()
pc=PlayerClass(fc)
gc=GameClass(fc, pc)
```

With DI, you can easily have access to the members you require once the setup phase is completed.

Answer (score 4):

To better understand your class relationships you have to tell us more about your project and what you are trying to accomplish.

One way to reference the *instance* of `FieldClass` from `PlayerClass` in your example is to pass the `GameClass` instance to the `PlayerClass` instance:

```
class PlayerClass:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
    def DoMagicHere(self):
        self.game.Field.AnswerAQuestion()

# ...

class GameClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.Field = FieldClass()
        self.Player = PlayerClass(self)
```

Another way is to pass the `field` variable

```
class PlayerClass:
    def __init__(self, field):
        self.field = field
    def DoMagicHere(self):
        self.field.AnswerAQuestion()
# ...

class GameClass:
    def __init__( self ):
        self.Field = FieldClass()
        self.Player = PlayerClass(self.Field)
```

As a side note: you use a peculiar naming scheme. I suggest this:

```
 class Game:
     def __init__(self):
         self.field = Field()
         self.player = Player(...)
```

I suggest you read the [Python Style Guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) before acquiring bad habits.

Comment: Thanks for the info on the naming scheme problem

Answer (score 1):

You could provide the context to the child objects, i.e.:

```
class FieldClass:
  def __init__(self,game):
   self.game = game

class PlayerClass:
  def __init__(self,game):
    self.game = game
  def DoMagicHere(self):
    self.game.Field.AnswerAQuestion()

class GameClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Field = FieldClass(self)
    self.Player = PlayerClass(self)
```

Since the objects know their context they can reach into it and access other objects in the same context.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like the following, where you pass Game in as a back-reference, allowing you access to the other associated classes.  In this way, you could optionally give that player instance a direct relationship to the field.

```
class FieldClass(object):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.Game = game
    def AnswerAQuestion(self):    
        return 42

class PlayerClass(object):
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.Game = game
        self.Field = game.Field # Optional
    def DoMagicHere(self):
        self.Game.Field.AnswerAQuestion()
        self.Field.AnswerAQuestion() # Optional

class GameClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Field = FieldClass(self)
        self.Player = PlayerClass(self)
```

One side note is that it's good practice now to have all your classes inherit from `object` rather than to have them standing alone.